# Understanding printed output for a BST traversal

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I'm trying to understand how the below code works. The code executes as it should but I don't understand parts of it.

It's a method for an in-order traversal of a binary search tree:

```
def traverse(self):
    def io(node):
        print("restart") #added to code see whats happening
        if node is not None: print("b4 app", node.data) #added to code see whats happening
        if node.left: io(node.left)
        result.append(node.data)
        if node is not None: print("aft app",node.data,node.right is None) #added to code see whats happening
        if node.right: #[1] skipped bc node.right is None
            print("inside right") #added to code see whats happening
            io(node.right)
    if self.root is None:
        return None
    else:
        result=[]
        io(self.root)
        return result
```

Here is the structure of the `Node` class for the Binary Search Tree:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
```

Here's the output traversing a BST:

```
restart
b4 app 9
restart
b4 app 4 #[3]
restart
b4 app 3 
aft app 3 True # <--- I thought it would end here? [0]
aft app 4 False #[2]
inside right
restart
b4 app 6
aft app 6 True
aft app 9 False
inside right
restart
b4 app 17
aft app 17 True
[3, 4, 6, 9, 17] #<-- ordered list of nodes (this output is correct)
```

The BST it's traversing:

```
"""
         9
        / \
       4   17
      / \
     3   6
"""
```

After the function gets to the point that I pointed to (see `[0]`), `node.right` is `None`, therefore the next `if` statement in the code is skipped (see `[1]`). This is the last time where the code calls itself again before it ends (as far as I can see?).

If this `if` statement is skipped -- last time the `io` function is called -- how does the recursion continue?

Also, as can be seen by the next line in the output (see `[2]`), it continues with `node=4`, `node.left=3`, `node.right=6`, which is `node=3`'s parent and was passed into the function early (see `[3]`).

So how was the `io` function called again and why is `node=4` the input?

Comment: You either need to add returns or convert some of your `if`s to `elif`s. I recommend the former.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are returning `None` for an empty tree rather than just `[]`. It's not like `[]` is the in-order traversal for any other non-empty tree.

Comment: @erip the function works as written. if you add a return then it will end after the first iteration - I also don't understand why that is so if you know please explain thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is a very confusing way to write a [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) but it looks fundamentally correct. Additionally, the output is printed in unusual locations and with misleading labels, so let's rewrite this cleanly before moving on to your questions.

Here's a straightforward way to write an inorder binary tree traversal:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def inorder(self):
        def traverse(node):
            if node:
                yield from traverse(node.left)
                yield node
                yield from traverse(node.right)

        return traverse(self.root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Node = namedtuple("Node", "data left right")
    """
        9
       / \
      4   17
     / \
    3   6
    """
    tree = Tree(
        Node(
            9,
            Node(
                4,
                Node(3, None, None),  
                Node(6, None, None), 
            ),
            Node(17, None, None)
        )
    )

    for node in tree.inorder():
        print(node.data, end=" ") # => 3 4 6 9 17
```

The only branch we need is to check whether the root is None--it's best to avoid worrying about the child recursive calls. If they're None, this single branch will handle that condition in the child [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

The above code returns a [generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) which is more memory-friendly than creating a list and is syntactically simpler.

I'd also keep printing outside of the function. Passing in a callback is a common way to avoid producing a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), but using the generator approach above the same outcome is accomplished with a loop, letting us keep the print in the caller.

If you do need to print for debugging purposes, I recommend using whitespace indentation which makes the output into a tree and much easier to follow:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def inorder(self):
        def traverse(node, depth=0):
            if node:
                yield from traverse(node.left, depth + 1)
                yield node, depth
                yield from traverse(node.right, depth + 1)

        return traverse(self.root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Node = namedtuple("Node", "data left right")
    """
        9
       / \
      4   17
     / \
    3   6
    """
    tree = Tree(
        Node(
            9,
            Node(
                4,
                Node(3, None, None),  
                Node(6, None, None), 
            ),
            Node(17, None, None)
        )
    )

    for node, depth in tree.inorder():
        print(" " * (depth * 2) + str(node.data))
```

This gives a side-view of the tree:

```
    3
  4
    6
9
  17
```

With this indentation trick to make it easier to visualize the tree, here's a cleaned-up version of your pre/in/post-order printing which should give a clear picture of the traversal:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def print_traversals_pedagogical(self):
        preorder = []
        inorder = []
        postorder = []

        def traverse(node, depth=0):
            if node:
                preorder.append(node.data)
                print("    " * depth + f"entering {node.data}")
                traverse(node.left, depth + 1)
                inorder.append(node.data)
                print("    " * depth + f"visiting {node.data}")
                traverse(node.right, depth + 1)
                postorder.append(node.data)
                print("    " * depth + f"exiting {node.data}")

        traverse(self.root)
        print("\npreorder ", preorder)
        print("inorder  ", inorder)
        print("postorder", postorder)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Node = namedtuple("Node", "data left right")
    """
        9
       / \
      4   17
     / \
    3   6
    """
    tree = Tree(
        Node(
            9,
            Node(
                4,
                Node(3, None, None),  
                Node(6, None, None), 
            ),
            Node(17, None, None)
        )
    )
    tree.print_traversals_pedagogical()
```

Output:

```
entering 9
    entering 4
        entering 3
        visiting 3
        exiting 3
    visiting 4
        entering 6
        visiting 6
        exiting 6
    exiting 4
visiting 9
    entering 17
    visiting 17
    exiting 17
exiting 9

preorder  [9, 4, 3, 6, 17]
inorder   [3, 4, 6, 9, 17]
postorder [3, 6, 4, 17, 9]
```

Now we can connect the above output with your code and clear up some of the confusion.

First of all, let's translate your output labels to match the ones shown above:

- `restart` does the same thing as `b4 app` so you should ignore it to avoid confusion. The `if node is not None: print("b4 app", node.data)` is always true--we guarantee in the caller that `node` will not be None.
- `b4 app` -> `entering` (or pushing a new call onto the stack).
- `aft app` -> `visiting` (inorder). Once again, `if node is not None:` is guaranteed true and should be removed. The parent call checks this and even if they didn't, the program would crash on the line above which uses `node.data`.
- `inside right` is confusing--it's an inorder print but only for nodes that have a right child. I'm not sure what value this adds so I'd ignore it.

Note that you have no `exiting` (popping a call stack frame/postorder) print statement.

With this context, let's answer your questions:

> This is the last time where the code calls itself again before it ends (as far as I can see?).

Yes, this node is about to be exited. To be clear, the *function* calls itself because it's recursive, but there's only exactly one call per node in the tree.

> If this `if` statement is skipped -- last time the `io` function is called -- how does the recursion continue?

The call stack pops and execution continues where it left off in the parent. It's not the last time `io` was called because the parent can (and its parents or its parents' children) can (and do) spawn other calls.

> So how was the `io` function called again and why is `node=4` the input?

It wasn't called again--the call frame for `node=4` was paused waiting for its children to resolve and when control returned to it, it continued where it left off.

Let's relate my output to your output:

```
    visiting 3  # this is your `aft app 3 True [0]`
    exiting 3   # you don't have this print for leaving the node
visiting 4      # this is your `aft app 4 False #[2]`
```

You can see we exited the call frame for `node=3`. At that point, `node=4` had completed traversing all of its left descendants (there is only one) and then visited its own value inorder before continuing with its right child.

Try playing with different tree structures in the above code and compare the printed debug/pedagogical traversal to your understanding.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Thats an interesting way to do it and alot of other good info i appreciate it. I will look into your implementation. Are you able to explain whats happening in the recursive function I posted tho? If you need more into let me know.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure what to explain--the code isn't how you'd typically write a recursive function like this because the logic consistently operates on children rather than the current node. It's best to stick to checking the current node for none and letting the recursion handle the children. The result list in your code appears to be correct based on looking at the implementation (I can't see your input tree, so the example output isn't meaningful to me) and `aft app 3 True` is normal behavior because two (or more) frames can be popped off the stack without right children.

Comment: My comment was too long so I rephrased the question and added more info - please take a look! Since nothing is being returned - how does the stack factor into the previous executions of the function?

Comment: Please show the tree you're working with (see my answer--there's an image of the tree along with the output which makes it easy to reason about the printed output). The stack is popped and other functions are waiting to explore their branches is about all I can say--return value irrelevant. Your prints are (as far as I can tell) arranged in correct preorder/inorder/postorder, so you'll see the preorder print when calls push onto the stack, inorder print after all left hand children are explored and postorder print when calls pop the stack.

Comment: I added a simplified tree structure to the question and changed the returns accordingly. "The stack is popped and other functions are waiting to explore their branches is about all I can say--return value irrelevant." <-- this kinda what im looking for I just wanted to understand how/why fully

Comment: I added more to the explanation--hopefully i helps clear things up a bit.